# Ransomeware : Decrypt files got encrypted by cerber program

Tags: ransomware

One of my friend, By mistake executed `.bat` file. By which a *opensans.tff* file was moved  to **temp directory** and was executed using `run` command. Outcome was that the program pulled all the files with extention like

1. .jpg
2. .png
3. .docx
4. etc

And converted this files in to encrypted files. Which are not in readable format. Now, the catch here is that if i want thoes file back then I will have to pay ransome and that is **BITCOIN**

I did lots of info gathering but all in vain. I am not able to figure out any method of recovering them back.

Guys here i need help your help to fix this issue. Any method or approach to get those file will be appreciated.